# How to get a single value of array which is returned by ajax call in success function using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to display welcome message to the user with his name...on next page but without redirecting the page(url should not be changed) for the same I have used ajax call and stores data in MySQL database.It works fine,stores data,returns array of values in success function of ajax call,but how to get the first name from that array which is returned by ajax call..
Can anyone please help me for the same..
Thank you..

Here is the block of code...which I have used..
$('document').ready(function () {

```
            $('#f1').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'process.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $('#f1').serialize(),
                    datatype:'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                         $('body').html('Welcome ' + data.fname);

                    }
                });
```

This returns on next page as Welcome undefined

And if I modified it as-
$('document').ready(function () {

```
            $('#f1').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'process.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $('#f1').serialize(),
                    datatype:'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                         $('body').html('Welcome ' + data);

                    }
                });
```

This returns output like below-
Welcome 1{"fname":"test","lname":"test","pnum":"1234567890","email":"test@gmail.com","gender":"f","status":"married"}

Comment: show some code which you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

php function called by ajax:

```
<?php
// your code logic

    $array = array('fname' => 'Pooja', 'lname' => 'Singh');
    echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

ajax:

```
success: function(response)  // here response is an json object so you have to parse it.
{
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    // data.fname contains Pooja
    // data.lname contains Singh, Show it where ever you required.
}
```

Comment: Your answer help me. but there is some syntax issue, I tried your code and I got an error, then I use $array = array () and it's working. Upvote from my side

Comment: @user9437856 thanks for pointing the mistake, I forgot to add `array` :D